# Switch login between normal user and admin user

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i want to develop an app where the user can choose to login into a normal user account or an admin account. So basically, when he launch the app, he will be asked to click on 2 buttons, one `user normal` and one `admin`. How can i manage that in swift ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create a Navigation Controller,then create a viewController Add 2 buttons in it. Create a segue for both buttons to the next viewController i.e your actual loginPage.(drag from the first icon to your actual login page)

[image: drag from the first icon]

Click on the segue and click 4th icon on the attribute inspector (top right side)
On textfield next to identifier , name it (eg : AdminLogin)
Click on the other segue and do the same  and name it UserLogin.

Create actions for each button on your viewController class

```
    @IBAction func ActionLoginAdmin(_ sender: Any) {

performSegue(withIdentifier: "AdminLogin", sender: nil)
}


    @IBAction func ActionuserAdmin(_ sender: Any) {

performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserLogin", sender: nil)
}
```

***This is the basic. Please don't post questions like this. Learn something and post what you have tried.***